# How to use the new android-maps-compose library in a scrollable Column?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I just switched from google maps with AndroidView to this compose library (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose), and I can't get the scrolling to work properly. I used to use this one:

```
map.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener {
     mapView?.parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)  
}
map.setOnCameraIdleListener {
     mapView?.parent?.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)  
}
```

What would be a similar solution in the new library?

```
GoogleMap(
properties = mapProperties,
cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
modifier = Modifier.clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
uiSettings = MapUiSettings(mapToolbarEnabled = false)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun Modifier.onPointerInteractionStartEnd(
    onPointerStart: () -> Unit,
    onPointerEnd: () -> Unit,
) = pointerInput(onPointerStart, onPointerEnd) {
    awaitEachGesture {
        awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
        onPointerStart()
        do {
            val event = awaitPointerEvent()
        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
        onPointerEnd()
    }
}

var isMapMoving by remember { mutableStateOf(false)

Column(
    Modifier.verticalScroll(
        rememberScrollState(), 
        enabled = !isMapMoving
    )
) {
    MapComposable(
        modifier = Modifier.onPointerInteractionStartEnd(
            onPointerStart = {
                isMapMoving = true
            },
            onPointerEnd = {
                isMapMoving = false
            }
        )
    )

}
```

Comment: This works well for two finger pan, but for single finger, does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.2.0 of Maps Compose, calling `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` is not possible on those events as Maps Compose completely manages the underlying map. There is an existing issue on the Maps Compose GitHub library (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/14) for this which you can follow.